# Weblogic CLOB column storing JSON - Error ORA-02290

Tags: json, weblogic, oracle-adf, clob

We are trying to save JSON string to the database column defined as CLOB. We get the below error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02290: check constraint (MYSCHEMA.MY_JSON_CHK) violated

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:466)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:407)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:603)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:234)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:55)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1006)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1316)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5010)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5136)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1519)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:170)
```

**Version:** Weblogic 12.2.1.2

- Attempted two data types at application ORM layer for this column
  java.sql.Clob & oracle.jbo.domain.ClobDomain
- Direct update via SQL works good
- Enabled & Disabled [wrapping of datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E80149_01/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/jdbc/jdbc_datasources/DisableWrapping.html) in weblogic
  JDBC datasource.

Comment: - I have not tried BLOB yet though I did check the database CHARACTERSET and found it to be the correct one - AL32UTF8..
- Modifying the VARCHAR2 maximum size is a DBA route and may be shot down by DBA asking us on reasons why we cannot use a CLOB with "in row" storage option..

But I attempted to switch my java ORMattribute from Clob back to a plain String and this worked. Any fall-side to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to switch my EO (ORM) attribute from oracle.jbo.ClobDomain back to a plain String and this worked.